# Angular : reload a html block when new data come from observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Under my **angular** app , I've this **component** view :

***component.html:***

```
    <div *ngIf="MY_VARIABLE==1" class="ScrollStyle2">
      <div style="display: none;">
        <app-button-config-file [dataPtfName]="nouveau_data"></app-button-config-file>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let content of datasalle.PTF_CONTENT">
            <div class=" col-sm-6"  *ngIf="content.VERSION.includes(strVersion)">
              <app-cards [content]="content" [dataPtf]="nouveau_data"></app-cards>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, Entire block is wrapped with an `*ngIf` which depends on varibale "`MY_VARIABLE`"

My purpose is to reload this entire html block  (all the div ) whenever "`MY_VARIABLE`" changes ,

To note :

`MYVARIABLE` is changing depending on a service observable ::

***component.ts :***

```
getData(){
this.myservice.mySubject.susbscribe((data) => {

  this.MY_VARIABLE = data
})
}
```

**Suggestions ??**

Answer (score 1):

then simply use `this.myservice.mySubject` instead of `MY_VARIABLE` in the template. If you need its value - simply use `as` there too.

```js
    <div *ngIf="myservice.mySubject | async as MY_VARIABLE" class="ScrollStyle2">
      <div style="display: none;">
        <app-button-config-file [dataPtfName]="nouveau_data"></app-button-config-file>
      </div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div *ngFor="let content of datasalle.PTF_CONTENT">
            <div class=" col-sm-6"  *ngIf="content.VERSION.includes(strVersion)">
              <app-cards [content]="content" [dataPtf]="nouveau_data"></app-cards>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

if `this.myservice.mySubject` should be called at some point (not always). then you can use `Subject` instead of `MY_VARIABLE`.

```js
MY_VARIABLE$ = new Subject();

getData(){
  this.myservice.mySubject.subscribe((data) => {
    this.MY_VARIABLE$.next(data);
  });
}
```

and the same thing in template as above but with `MY_VARIABLE$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReplaySubject(2) to store old and new values which you can compare and load if different.